# Как убрать .html из строки поиска при статичной генерации в next js

Tags: reactjs, url, nextjs

я строю сайт на статической генерацти используя next.js. посля "next build && next export"
в папке out формируется статический сайт где для каждой страницы формируется файлик как pageName.html. После этого содержимое папки летит на сервер(обычный php). И чтобы зайти на каждую страницу в поисковой строке необходимо добавить .html чтобы попасть на нужную страницу. Но если переходить по ссылке сделаной через Next/link то страница открывается без .html. как можно изменить это поведение?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй при загрузке на хостинг в файле package.json добавить строчку
`"homepage":"https://sitename/`

Также попробуй создать .htaccess фаил:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ — [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>.
```